# Why do I have these KDE processes running in Xubuntu?

Tags: process, kde, xubuntu

I have Xubuntu 16.04. I was looking at the Task Manager and I found several KDE processes running: `knotify4, kuiserver, kdeinit4:kded4 [kdeinit], kactivitymanagerd start-daemon, kdeinit4:klauncher [kdeinit] --fd=8, kdeinit4:kdeinit4 Running...`

[kdeinit4](https://linux.die.net/man/8/kdeinit4) seeems to be used only to run KDE applications.

Is this perhaps due to some application I am running, which is KDE-specific? I can't think on one. I had a look at all my packages installed and found these with `kde` on it:

```
kde-runtime/xenial,now 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kde-runtime-data/xenial,xenial,now 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
kde-style-breeze/xenial,now 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kde-style-breeze-qt4/xenial,now 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kdelibs-bin/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kdelibs5-data/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 all [installed,automatic]
kdelibs5-plugins/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkde3support4/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkdeclarative5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkdecore5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkdesu5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkdeui5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkdewebkit5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qml-module-org-kde-activities/xenial,now 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols/xenial,now 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons/xenial,now 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

All of them seem pretty official.

Can I safely kill the processes listed at the beginning, and perhaps uninstall them?

Comment: There are several "kde" applications that don't have "kde" in their package names. Some examples are dolphin, gwenview, kate, and krita.

Comment: You could run `apt-get remove -s libqt4* | grep Remv | cut -d ' ' -f 2` and `apt-get remove -s libqt5* | grep Remv | cut -d ' ' -f 2` to get more exhaustive output. The `-s` indicates you're running a *simulation* and so you don't need `sudo` and nothing will actually be removed.

Comment: @DKBose I can recognise audacity, mixxx, openshot, okular, and vlc, all of which I use. Full output [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pVtstz7YW2/).

Comment: Well, then my guess is you're running some "kde" application when you see those processes.